# ostream equivalent of %.2f or %.2lf

Tags: c++, iostream, precision

```
double d = 1/2.;
printf("%.2lf\n", d);
```

This prints out `0.50`.  This is what I want to replicate using ostream manipulators.  However, none of the obvious `iomanip` manipulators let me set the minimum required decimal places (if I understood correctly, `setprecision` sets the maximum width). Is there a pure `iostream` or `boost` way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setprecision` in combination with `fixed`.

According to section 22.4.2.2.2 of the standard, precision specifications on iostreams have exactly the same effect as they do for `printf`.  And `fixed` gives the exact same behavior as `printf`'s `%f`.

Comment: @FooBah: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Answer (score 13):

You can use `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision` from the `iomanip` header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main(void) {
    double d = 1.0 / 2;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << d << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `0.50` as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The boost way: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/format/doc/format.html.

Comment: Wow, that's like trying to kill a mosquito with a thermo-nuclear warhead :-)

Comment: @paxdiable: No it solves a real problem. `printf` is not type-safe (and works with a handful of types), with streams formatting is painful (and in certain cases you absolutely need to be able to use a format string).